# How create two isolated AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, appdomain, awesomium

I need to create 2 totaly isolated AppDomain and run 2 separate copies of Awesomium.WebCore (I can't run 2 copies in one application). The problem that when I am creating second copy of WebCore in other AppDomain I am getting the same  error as if I created in one AppDomain.

How I create AppDomain:

```
AppDomain.CreateDomain(RandomHelper.NextString(10));
```

Error when I am trying to initialize Awseomium.WebCore for the second time:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Awesomium.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: Perhaps you want to tell us what the error message you're seeing is, instead of asking how to create an `AppDomain` which you already seem to know how to do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This error happens only for Awesomium.WebCore when I am trying to initialize it for the second time. I posted ti to the topic.

Comment: You problem has nothing to do with AppDomains in general, but with the specific product you are using. Please look at the accepted answer of the duplicate. According to the Awesomeium documentation you get an AccessViolationException typically when you "attempted to access the member from a thread other than thread where WebCore was created."

Comment: Thank you for the helping. The problem that I am getting this error when I am creating WebCore. The same problem I can get when I am initializing the WebCore for the second time in the same AppDomain. That's why I thought that I am creating AppDomain not correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any problem with this line:

```
AppDomain.CreateDomain(RandomHelper.NextString(10));
```

But i thing is better that use this constructor:

```
public static AppDomain CreateDomain(
    string friendlyName,
    Evidence securityInfo,
    AppDomainSetup info,
    PermissionSet grantSet,
    params StrongName[] fullTrustAssemblies
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, maybe the problem with this?`Item item = (Item)_appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                typeof(Item).Assembly.FullName,
                "InnerThreading.Item");`